# Foreground extraction using opencv

Tags: opencv3.0, background-foreground

I am working on a dataset (training + testing) which contains a different shopping cart items (eg: biscuits, soaps etc..) with different backgrounds and I need to predict the product id for all testing images (product ids are unique for each product, Let's say Good-day 10 rs is having product id 1 and so on... for different products )

My approach was to :

1) extract the foreground from the image.

2) Apply  sift/surf algorithm for finding matching keypoints (or) train a faster RCNN...

I was thinking to build a Haar Cascade classifier, can anyone suggest an easy foreground extraction algorithm possible for this scenario in python ?

Comment: Could you please give a more detailed explaination about the dataset? Maybe share a sample image?

Comment: Actually the case is, I'm having foreground extracted images for training but need to predict the product id for testing images in the real-time scenario (where the background can be anything)

Comment: Do you need this operation to work at real-time?

Comment: Testing images consists of a single product and some random background..(Testing images are not provided yet , so can't share)

Comment: Yes (real-time)

Comment: A small doubt @Meto for applying YOLO is there a need of foreground extraction ??

Comment: No you don't need to apply foreground extraction for neither YOLO nor SSD models they should do that for you. I recommended these models because you told me that background can be dynamic.

Comment: i have implemented YOLO v3 , but the problem is in my dataset as no: of classes changes I need to retrain the yolov3 model which consumes too much time..                                             can you suggest more foreground extraction algorithms for my dataset other than Haar-cascade.

Comment: Could you update your problem with more details and provide more concrete examples. That way the whole community can help you more I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For real-time purposes I don't recommend the RCNN models since they are not built for realtime but for precision. Sift or surf can recognise scenes but if the object is deformed in some way they would fail easily. Haar cascade seems to be a good solution. I also recommend checking out [Yolo](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet) or [SSD models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) since they can be easily trained with transfer learning and they are very successfull at realtime object classification. Opencv also has a DNN module for running these kinds of neural networks.